# What is the value of $\sum_{r=0}^n a^rb^{n-r}$

Tags: summation

How can I calculate the summation 
$$\sum_{r=0}^n a^rb^{n-r}$$

Comment: That's a geometric progression.

Comment: Please can u help me in,this i thought to solve this by binomial

Comment: Hint: $a^rb^{n-r} = (a/b)^rb^n$.

Comment: Hint: $a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\cdots+a b^{n-2}+b^{n-1})\,$.

Comment: @KumarNikhil: Please write standard English.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression

Comment: Please explain in detail

Comment: My ques has a=2 and b=1/2

Comment: I think mosquite's hint is already rather detailed, but the next step: $\sum\limits_{r=0}^na^rb^{n-r}=\sum\limits_{r=0}^n(\frac{a}{b})^rb^n = b^n\sum\limits_{r=0}^n(\frac{a}{b})^r$, then use what you know about geometric series.

Comment: Oh wow i solved this

Comment: Yes b^n is a constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [geometric progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression) we have:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n a^kb^{n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^kb^n=b^n\left(\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}\right)$$
where $x=\dfrac{a}{b}$ and $x\neq 1$.

Note that if $x=1\iff \dfrac{a}{b}=1\iff a=b$, then we have:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^kb^n=\sum_{k=0}^nb^n=(n+1)b^n$$

Comment: Thanks dave..!!